# How to bind selected item of checkbox list to a selected item in a dropdownlist in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, checkbox

I am implementing in Ruby on Rails and in my application, i first have a list with checkboxes with next to it a dropdownlist. If i check my checkbox it means that this item is enabled, and you can select a role for this item in a dropdownlist. Now my question is how can i bind these two things to each other. I can't find something like that on the internet. I only have my checkboxlist in my view and it looks like this:

```
  <%= principals_check_box_tags 'member[group_id][]', @groups %>
```

and @groups is filled in my controller by:

```
 @groups = Group.active.find(:all)
```

Someone who can help me out of this and how things have to be written?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to enable or disable the dropdown on change of the checkbox. To track the checkbox and corresponding dropdown, make the html id of dropdown as

> "dropdwon_#{group_id}"

Initially when page is loaded keep all the dropdown disabled as

```
<%=f.select :dropdown1, options, :html=>{:disabled=>true, :id => "dropdwon_#{group_id}"} %>
```

and on change of the checkbox simply enable the dropdown

Comment: so how will my view look like? because i do not get it for the 100 % ;). But it is also possible that there are more or less checkboxes...